# JuMPDict change of dimension

Tags: dictionary, julia, dimensions, julia-jump

I am using Julia 0.6.2 and JuMP 0.18.5 (I can't use a more recent version since I need to use an old package).

Creating JuMP variables with conditions on the index lead to a JuMPDict instead of an Array.

For example:

```
m = Model(solver = CplexSolver())

# type of x: JuMP.JuMPDict{JuMP.Variable,2}
@variable(m, x[i in 1:3, j in 1:3; i < j] >= 0) 

# type of y: JuMP.JuMPDict{JuMP.Variable,3}
@variable(m, y[i in 1:3, j in 1:3, k in 1:3; i < j] >= 0)
```

I would like to apply a function f to x and to y[:, :, k] for all k in 1:3. However, I don't know how to define such a generic function.

I tried to set the argument type of f to JuMP.JuMPDict{JuMP.Variable,2}:

```
function f(input::JuMP.JuMPDict{JuMP.Variable,2})
    ...
end
```

I can use the function on x but not on y:

```
f(x) # Works
for k in 1:3
    f(y[:, :, k]) # does not work as y is not an array
end
```

My last idea was to convert y into several JuMP.JuMPDict{JuMP.Variable,2}:

```
function convertTo2D(dict3D::JuMP.JuMPDict{JuMP.Variable,3}, k::Int)

    dict2D = JuMP.JuMPDict{JuMP.Variable,2}() # This line returns "ERROR: KeyError: key :model not found"

    for (key, value) in keys(dict3D)
        if key[3] == k
            dict2D[(key[1], key[2])] = value # Not sure if it will work
        end
    end

    return dict2D
end
```

If this was working I could use:

```
for k in 1:3
    f(convertTd2D(y, k))
end
```

Do you know how I could fix convertTo2D or do what I want another way?

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous variables solved my problem. Thanks to them I can successively create the variables of y in a for loop. Variable y is now an array of "2D dictionaries" rather than a "3D dictionaries":

```
y = Array{JuMP.JuMPDict{JuMP.Variable,2}, 1}([])

for k in 1:3
    yk = @variable(m, [i in 1:3, j in 1:3; i < j] >= 0)
    f(yk)
    push!(y, yk)
end
```